# Stub out Google Maps geocoder for testing

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, sinon

I'm trying to create a test for a geocoding function that uses Google Maps API Geocoder service

```
function geocodeLocation(zipcode){

  const service = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    service.geocode( {'address': zipcode}, function(results, status){
      if (status === 'OK') {
        const lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat()
        const lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng()
        resolve([lat, lng])
      } else {
        reject(status)
      }
    })
  }).then((response) => {
    return response;
  })
}
```

I've also created a `google` window object that is supposed to represent the google api objects on the page. The following snipping is being imported to the test file.

```
window.google = {
  maps: {
    DistanceMatrixService: noop,
    Geocoder: noop,
    ZoomControlStyle: EMPTY_OBJECT,
  },
};
```

I'm under the assumption that I should now do this in order to stub the geocoder function:

`stub(google.maps.Geocoder(), 'geocode')`

However, i'm presented with this:

`TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent own property geocode`

Is this just syntax that i'm tripping over, or is my implementation off?Ideally, I just want to test that my function `geocodeLocation` returns an object with lat/long coordinates.

Comment: nothing to do with your problem - but your Promise is a bit off ... if status is not 'OK', the promise will remain pending forever - rather than `return false` you may want to `reject(status)`

Comment: `'geocoder'` ... vs ... `geocode` - is that a typo perhaps?

Comment: Yes that is a typo. I will change the `else` condition to `reject` as well

Comment: no, not `Promise.reject(status)` ... `reject(status)` - you're in a Promise executor function